# Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64 mac os library Clion error

Tags: c++, macos, clang, clion, clang++

I am trying to build my library and link it to the project. But I get an error. The compiler does not see the implementation of the F::method(); function in lesson6.cpp. Why? Can anyone explain what the error is?

**Error**

```
====================[ Build | lesson6 | Debug ]=================================
/Applications/CLion.app/Contents/bin/cmake/mac/bin/cmake --build /Users/mbp15/CLionProjects/lesson6/cmake-build-debug --target lesson6 -- -j 6
Scanning dependencies of target lesson6
[ 50%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/lesson6.dir/app/main.cpp.o
[100%] Linking CXX executable lesson6
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "F::method(int, int)", referenced from:
      _main in main.cpp.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
make[3]: *** [lesson6] Error 1
make[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/lesson6.dir/all] Error 2
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/lesson6.dir/rule] Error 2
make: *** [lesson6] Error 2
```

**Cmake.h**

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.17)

project(lesson6 VERSION 1.0.0 DESCRIPTION "Lesson project" LANGUAGES CXX)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 20)

add_executable(lesson6 app/main.cpp)

add_library(MyLibrary include/lesson6.h src/lesson6.cpp)

target_link_libraries(lesson6 PUBLIC ${MyLibrary})
```

**main.cpp**

```
#include "../include/lesson6.h"

int main(){

    F object;

    object.method(1,2);

    return 0;
}
```

**lesson6.h**

```
#ifndef LESSON6_LESSON6_H
#define LESSON6_LESSON6_H

class F {

public:

    int method(int one, int two);

};

#endif //LESSON6_LESSON6_H
```

**lesson6.cpp**

```
#include "../include/lesson6.h"

int F::method(int one, int two) {
    return one + two;
}
```

[Project tree](https://i.stack.imgur.com/re0nn.png)

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to dereference the library target in your CMakeLists.txt.

Try changing the last line to

```
target_link_libraries(lesson6 PUBLIC MyLibrary)
```